# Clarify: "$S^0$, $S^1$ and $S^3$ are the only spheres which are also groups"

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, real-numbers, quaternions, spheres

The zero, one, and three dimensional spheres $S^0$, $S^1$ and $S^3$ are in bijection with the sets $\{a\in \mathbb{K}:|a|=1\}$ for $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}$ respectively.
The real, complex and quaternionic multiplication therefore provide a group operation on these spheres.

This is mentioned in the book: Kristopher Tapp (2011), Matrix Groups for Undergraduates, Indian Edition, pp. 40.

Following this there is a statement:

> It turns out that $S^0$, $S^1$ and $S^3$ are the only spheres which are also groups.

Can someone please clarify this statement?
How are these three the only spheres which are also groups?

For example, I could take any sphere $S^k$ ($k\ge 1$) and get a bijection $f:S^k \to S^1$ and define a binary operation on $S^k$ by $$a*b = f^{-1}(f(a)\cdot f(b))$$
and $S^k$ would be a group under this operation.

So what exactly is meant by the above statement? In what sense are these the only three spheres which are also groups?

Comment: The point is that the operation gotten from such a set-theoretical bijection has no reason to respect the topological/differentiable structure of $S^k$ in any way. So what they mean is, a group structure in $S^k$ that behaves well with respect to the topology/geometry. (Hence the Lie groups appearing in the answer below).

Comment: This is a theorem of Samuelson.   See:  Samelson, H., ¨Uber die Spharen, die als Gruppenr¨aume auftreten, Comm. Math. Helvetici, 13 145-155.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The highlighted statement in your question means that the only spheres with **group structures compatible with their smooth structure** (i.e. multiplication by any fixed element and taking inverse are smooth) are $S^0$, $S^1$ and $S^3$. In other words the only spheres which are also **Lie groups** are those three spheres (for otherwise, any spheres can be made a group by means of a set theoretic bijection between the sphere and $(S^1, \cdot)$, as you rightly pointed out).

That $S^0$, $S^1$ and $S^3$ are the only spheres with smooth group structure (i.e. Lie groups) can be deduced using Chevalley-Eilenberg's Lie algebra cohomology. We may first limit our search for spheres with Lie group structure to $S^n$ for $n>1$ as we already know $S^0$ and $S^1$ are Lie groups. If $S^n$ is a Lie group, then it is a compact and simply-connected one and hence must be semi-simple. It is known that cohomology of a compact Lie group $G$ is isomorphic to the Lie algebra cohomology of $\mathfrak{g}$, and that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, then $H^3(\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{R})\neq 0$ (a 3-form which represents a nonzero third Lie algebra cohomology class is $\alpha(X, Y, Z)=\langle X, [Y, Z]\rangle$, where $\langle, \rangle$ is the Killing form). Thus $H^3(S^n)\neq 0$ and $n$ must be 3. As it turns out, $S^3\cong SU(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

The spheres $S^0,S^1$ and $S^3$ are the only spheres that are lie groups (a group that is a differentiable manifold as well). The proof uses the group cohomology (ie, studying groups using cohomology theory) of spheres. Check out the De Rham cohomology of the $n-$dimensional sphere, which states that $H^1(S^n\times I)$ and $H^3(S^n\times I)$ both equal $0$ as long as $n$ does not equal $1$ or $3$ (in this case). Here, $I$ is a real and open interval (eg, the real numbers). Check out the following links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#The_n-sphere
http://planetmath.org/spheresthatareliegroups