# Bijection between $S^1$ and $S^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres

I have read in this post [Clarify: "$S^0$, $S^1$ and $S^3$ are the only spheres which are also groups"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310657/clarify-s0-s1-and-s3-are-the-only-spheres-which-are-also-groups) that there is a bijection between  $S^1$ and the sphere $S^n$, $n \geq 1$ and this was confirmed in the answer!

What is an explicit bijection $f : S^1 \rightarrow S^n$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Both are clearly uncountable, and contained in $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$, so they must have cardinality $\aleph_1$. So, you get a bijection.

Comment: @MathIsNice1729 $\aleph_1$ is not necessarily the cardinality of $\Bbb R$. (continuum hypothesis)

Comment: @KennyLau Continuum hypothesis is pretty well-accepted though, so I guess we should be able to use it.

Comment: @MathIsNice1729 *Continuum hypothesis is pretty well-accepted though* That is really **not the case**! You have results with or without it. No more than that.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net What do you mean? I know that it's not provable under ZFC but in my (rather limited) experience, I've always seen that it's assumed to be true in mainstream mathematics. Isn't it?

Comment: Please define what *mainstream mathematics* is! The continuum hypothesis is not assumed in mathematics as a usual axiom.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Look, I get your point. It's not provable, so we get two different answers. But just like axiom of choice, I've seen that it's usually assumed in most textbooks/research work.

Comment: *I've seen that it's usually assumed in most textbooks/research work* really not what I experience. If you can quote some usual math books (analysis, calculus...) where it is assumed that would convince me. What *classical math theorem* assumes continuum hypothesis?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Now that I think about it, it was dumb of me to say that. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point seeking an explicit bijection. It will not have any special property. It will not be close to continuous.

$S^1$ and $S^n$ are in bijection because they have the same cardinality, and here is why:

If you remove a point from each of them, then you end up with $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^n$ because of the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).

Now, $\Bbb R$ clearly injects into $\Bbb R^n$, so by the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), we only need to inject $\Bbb R^n$ back into $\Bbb R$: given $(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in \Bbb R^n$, let $0.a_{i1}a_{i2} \cdots$ be the **binary** expansion of $\frac1{1+\exp(x_i)}$
(this is the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), an injection $\Bbb R \to (0, 1)$). Then say that the result is $0.a_{11} a_{21} \cdots a_{n1} a_{12} a_{22} \cdots a_{n2} \cdots$ as **ternary**. This different base is taken to avoid things like $0.012022222\ldots_3 = 0.121_3$. Then this gives an injection $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, so we are done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !